# Get Top 50 IPs from access.log including IPV6

Tags: apache, shell, ubuntu, ssh

I often use this to check website access logs by IP address. The problem is that it only includes IPV4 and not IPV6.

Any idea what regex I can use so that it includes (or runs a separate) command for IPV6?

```
cat access.log | sed -e 's/^\([[:digit:]\.]*\).*"\(.*\)"$/\1 \2/' | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matching IP addresses via regular expressions can be tricky - yours matches lots of things that aren't valid IPv4 addresses, like `100000.55`, for example.

There's a `perl` module, [Regexp::Common](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Common) that provides well tested regular expressions for matching all sorts of things, including both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. If you install it (The Ubuntu package is `libregexp-common-perl`), you can replace the `sed` part of that pipeline with

```
perl -MRegexp::Common=net -lne '/^($RE{net}{IPv4}|$RE{net}{IPv6}).*"(.*)"$/ && print "$1 $2"'
```

to match both address families.